# encode with webcodecs and forward to gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, webcodecs

I'm encoding a videoframe using HTML5 native webcodecs into raw h264 (without transport)
With the following configuration

```
    videoEncoder.configure({
        codec: 'avc1.420034',
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        bitrate: 1e6,
        avc: {
            format: 'annexb'
        },
        framerate: 30,
        bitrateMode: 'constant'
    })
```

I'm sending the video over a websocket to java server and then over udp to gstreamer

The following example open a local windows with the video

`gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5555 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264, profile=baseline ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink`

but I'm trying to send over srt to a cloud server

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5555 ! video/x-h264, profile=baseline ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! queue ! srtsink uri="srt://REDACTED:10000"
```

the pipeline starts but I cannot watch the video online.
And after a few seconds the following message appears

```
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSRTSink:srtsink0: Error on SRT socket. Trying to reconnect.
Additional debug info:
../ext/srt/gstsrtobject.c(1790): gst_srt_object_write_one (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSRTSink:srtsink0:
libsrt reported: Unknown or erroneous
```

Comment: Is this solved now? If not, then confirm that the HTML tag in your browser supports reading from an `srt://` protocol. Also test if the output shows when using `http://` (or even `https://`) to check that the picture encoding part is not wrong...

Comment: **PS:** _"...But I cannot watch the video online"_ A `<video>` tag expects an `.m3u8` file if you're using `.ts` video files as the input source. I don't use GStreamer... but you need make settings that packages your H.264 into a fragmented MP4 instead of into a TS (Transport Stream) container. Also use a M3U8 file compatible player such as [VideoJS](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ZiTAL/434338d6d5cf9abdd47211f3e980aaa4/raw/3b44c301aa902b70900282f63ccb0f5d7c9a6578/index.html) for HTML5 (because only Safari plays M3U8 files automatically)..